# Parent DIV with floated div's as childs

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3fT2M/

Why isn't the two floated div background color isn't `#666666` even though they are under the `container` div?

It works only if I set the `container` height which I would like to set to `auto`.

How can I make it work with `.container { height: auto; }` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3fT2M/3/

Because the elemtns are floated inside the div.

This takes the element out of the normal flow of the document.

I've added the `overflow: hidden;` fix

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `div.container` has no height.  So you cannot see the `background-color`.

A simple fix is to add a `<br />` before the last closing `</div>`.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fT2M/2/

Comment: there is no need to modify the DOM to fix this. This should always be a last resort.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this answer was downvoted. BTW, You can use a clearing DIV instead of `BR`, it is a standard practice.

Comment: @Salman A - answer was downvoted by me at least because adding a <br /> at the bottom of the div doesn't solve my problem which is to have the background color cover both floated divs no matter what content they have inside. Using this solution, It will only cover the height of the <br />.

Comment: @Or W adding a clearing `<br />` is standard practice.  of course, there are other ways, but this works fine.  BTW, this will work no matter the `div.container` height.  See http://jsfiddle.net/3fT2M/10/

Comment: @Jason Gennaro - I'm trying to have the container height as ``auto``, not a specified height. Adding a ``<br />`` doesn't work in that case if you add more text to the floated divs.

Comment: @Or W Fair enough.  It will work fine if you `clear:both;` on the `<br />`.  http://jsfiddle.net/3fT2M/11/

Answer (score 0):

It also seems a simple `.container div{background: inherit;}` works.